# Download a local file using django?

Tags: python, django, oracle11g, django-templates

I have this project and I've been trying to download a file that is storaged in a local folder:

> 'C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/Media/'

Looking for similar questions I've found that I have to modify the settings 'MEDIA_ROOT'

This is the code that I'm using for the download:

```
    <tbody>
    {% if archivos %}
    {% for archivo in archivos %}
    <tr>

        <td>{{ archivo.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ archivo.transferido }} </td>
        <td>{{ archivo.fecha_creacion}}</td>
        <td>{{ archivo.observaciones }}</td>
        <td><a href= "C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/Media/{{archivo.documento}}" download ="{{archivo.nombre}}">Descargar</a> </td>
        <td>{{ archivo.estado}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
    <h1>No existen archivos registrados</h1>
    {% endif %}
</tbody>
```

This is my setting code:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/Media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'Media/'
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

[Error: Network Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78835.png)

I'm using oracle as DB just for storage the directory, and Django 1.10

Please help me...

Comment: If you have your media set up correctly, you should be able to access the assets with the media url: 'localhost:8000/Media/filename'. You need a web server to deliver the image.

Comment: @cdvv7788 I'm getting the same error for 'localhost:8000/Media/filename'. What do you mean "web server to deliver the image"?

Comment: When you are running "python manage.py runserver" you are running django's development server, which serves your site and your file. Whatever you have configured is under localhost:8000. Give this a read if you haven't yet: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Comment: @cdvv7788 Thanks man, I was missing the urlspatterns in my urls.py file.